# CiviCRM and GDPR Subject Access Requests

Tags: gdpr

Most ongoing GDPR matters are handled by the GDPR extension kindly provided by Veda Consulting, but there seems to be nothing available to deal with a GDPR Subject Access Request (SAR--effectively a dump of all data held on an individual). Perhaps I am missing something, but I don't see any way of doing this easily. Has anyone had to deal with a SAR in CiviCRM and have some suggestions? (We are not facing this immediately, but one wants to be prepared.) Thanks.

Comment: I would open an issue with feature request on GDPR extension page.

Comment: I have dealt with an SAR for a person who was a contact in Civi and was emailed there.  The good thing about Civi is that the data is obviously well organised, so that's not a problem.  The tricky bit is not so much with systems (although gmail was a problem as you can only forward one email at a time) and Civi certainly was not a problem.  The real problem was what to send, how much and what to redact.  Advice on that varies!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently v3.1 of the GDPR extension (released in Feb 2021) includes an export option in the GDPR tab:

- https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/issues/85

Comment: Yes, thanks.  That update was actually done at our request and with my organization's support.